# Can you horizontally scroll grid?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a vertically scrolling grid, with columns auto-fitted to the width.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  overflow-y: auto;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax($min-column-width, 1fr));
}
```

I'm now trying to make a horizontally scrolling grid, with rows auto-fitting to the height (basically a rotated version of the above) - but it's not as trivial as I thought.

I've tried this (with various variations):

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax($min-row-height, 1fr));
  grid-auto-flow: row;
}
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: for scrollbars to show up you need overflow combined with setting the overflow property to auto or scroll, either the items have a min-width or the grid columns do. your code is setting `grid-template-rows` and not the columns, and `grid-auto-flow` is set to row by default.

Answer (score 2):

Please put your html and css code in snippet.

try this for horizontally scrolling grid

```
    display: grid;
    gap: 16px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,minmax(160px,1fr));
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-auto-columns: minmax(160px,1fr);
    overflow-x: auto;
```

Comment: Tihs doesn't work, it just puts all elements in 1 row, all 160px each. I want the rows to auto-fit to the grid's height.

Comment: @Tobiq please put your html and css code in a snippet and explain more what you need exactly

Comment: I managed to fix it (you need to use `grid-template-rows`, here's the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-leftpad-bz5eop?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: But my question is, why do you need to do `minmax(160px,1fr)` twice, but with columns, you only need it once?

Comment: @Tobiq grid-auto-columns: minmax(160px,1fr); the items added outside the viewport do not match auto-fit, so they won't get the size defined in your template. So you have to define it again with grid-auto-columns.